# Populating jTable from database based on a column value entered in same table column

Tags: java, sql, swing, events, jtable

I have a jTable. It has 6 column. I need to enter name in column 1 and once I press enter key the other 5 columns must be populated from database. Can anyone help please?

```
  private void jTable2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    {

            int key = evt.getKeyCode();
             if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
             {
                 // Object s=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1);
            //System.out.println("Value" +s);
      Object Name= jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1);;

        try { 
            openconn();

            PreparedStatement ps;

            System.out.println("Val" +Name);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from inventory.addproducts where name='"+Name+"'");
            rs= ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    String rate=rs.getString(2);
                     jTable2.getModel().setValueAt(rate, 2, 3);
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wrong input");
                }
             conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
                  {

                  }

   }}
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you try already? Where were your problems? We are trying to help with specific problems, not document general approaches here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will make sense how to do it, use DefaultTableModel to populate your JTabel, a simple example, have not tried it out:

```
private DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
        private JTable table=new JTable(model);
        private JButton submit =new JButton("Submit");
        public void populate(){
            submit.addActionListener(e->{model.addRow(new Object[]{textField.getText(),database.getSurname(),database.getAge()});})

        }
```